# ORACLE: Using Column Name returned by function in SELECT statement

Tags: oracle, function, plsql

I want to automatically assign column aliases to multiple columns. My tables usually have min 20 columns. I am trying to avoid writing something like "column1 AS XXX_column1, column2 AS XXX_column2 ... x20".

I am new to PLSQL but I was hoping to use output from multiplied “column AS XXX_column” returned by function directly in standard SELECT clause.

So I have written a function (RETURN data type is VARCHAR2) to generate a column name. I want to use it directly in my SELECT statement. Below is simplified example of this:

--- Function

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION simple RETURN varchar2 IS
BEGIN
  RETURN ‘my_column’;
END simple;
```

--- Select

```
SELECT simple FROM my_table;
```

This does not work. It seems that output from function is passed as a quotation i.e.

```
SELECT ‘my_column’ FROM my_table;
```

So the output from SELECT is a list of rows populated with values my_table:

```
COLUMN  simple
ROW1    my_column
ROW2    my_column
ROW3    my_column
```

Can please someone help me with this?

Comment: Instead of posting some obscure code and expecting us to guess what you're trying to achieve why don't you just explain the scenario?

Comment: I want to automatically assign column aliases to multiple columns. My tables usually have min 20 columns. Writing something like "column1 AS XXX_column1, column2 AS XXX_column2 ... x20" is what I am trying to avoid. I am new to PLSQL but I was hoping to use output from multiplied “column AS XXX_column” returned by function directly in standard SELECT clause.

Comment: So your explanation reveals a question worth answering.  Unfortunately the question has already been closed so we can't answer it unless people vote to reopen.  The teaching here is, always explain what you're trying to do.  Bad or unclear questions have a short lifespan.

Answer (score 2):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION simple RETURN varchar2 IS
BEGIN
  RETURN ‘my_column’;
END simple;


--- Select
DECLARE
    myCol VARCHAR2(128);
BEGIN
    myCol := simple;
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'SELECT ' || myCol || ' FROM my_table';
END;
```

Comment: Thanks for quick reply. SELECT statement that you provided is inside PLSQL block. What I am looking for is to use my function in standard SQL (SELECT simple FROM my_table). Is it possible to do this? Maybe use different data type returned by function. I am just guessing.

Comment: I'm afraid dynamic sql is not standard sql.

Comment: what is the context? There's always a solution

Comment: I want to modify all column names in given table. Using aliases it’s not handy when there are lots of columns.

Comment: well why not creating a plsql block then? Are you saying you want to run several `ALTER TABLE` statements?

Comment: Renaming columns is only for displaying and mainly exporting output purpose. I do not want to alter column names. I quit often have to join several tables having the same column names. SQL Developer is adding numbers to them but that’s not very descriptive.

Comment: @zwornik Use a view with column names you like then.